# Define/get the language in Joomla with jQuery doesn't work

Tags: jquery, joomla, jquery-plugins, joomla2.5, joomla3.0

I have a text (1,00 EUR) which I want to replace with another text depending on the actual language... but unfortunately I'm unable to get the right value from the url with the following code, or something is going wrong:

```
if ((location.href.indexOf('/en/') > -1){
    $('.price').each(function() {
    var text = $(this).text();
    $(this).text(text.replace('1,00 EUR', 'Price upon request')); 
    });
}

if (location.href.indexOf('/de/') > -1) {
    $('.price').each(function() {
    var text = $(this).text();
    $(this).text(text.replace('1,00 EUR', 'Preis auf Anfrage')); 
    });
}

if (location.href.indexOf('/fr/') > -1) {
    $('.price').each(function() {
    var text = $(this).text();
    $(this).text(text.replace('1,00 EUR', 'Prix sur demande')); 
});
}
```

The class is price and the url is used for getting the language.

Thanks

Comment: is code being run inside a `document.ready` block so elements exist when code runs? Have you tried logging to console inside this code to be sure it is running? Any errors thrown in page?

Comment: Yes, it's being run inside ´document.ready´ and it works without the ´if statement´...

Comment: the `if`'s seem right...try running this code right from the console

Comment: nope, still doesn't work

Comment: hard to help more without access to page